# Как найти в тексте и заменить значение по маске?

Tags: php

Есть вот такая строка:
Здравствуйте **[~iname~]** мы знаем что ваша фамилия **[~fname~]**, поэтому **[~fname~]** **[~iname~]** мы дарим вам подарок.

Есть такой массив:
$arr['person']['iname']="Анатолий";
$arr['person']['fname']="Рожков";

Надо получить такую строку
Здравствуйте **Анатолий** мы знаем что ваша фамилия **Рожков**, поэтому **Рожков** **Анатолий** мы дарим вам подарок.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$str = "Здравствуйте [~iname~] мы знаем что ваша фамилия [~fname~], поэтому [~fname~] [~iname~] мы дарим вам подарок.";

$arr = [
 'person' => [
    'iname' => 'Анатолий',
    'fname' => 'Рожков'
  ]
];

foreach( array_keys( $arr['person'] ) as $key ) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\[\~".$key."\~\]/", $arr['person'][ $key ], $str );
}

echo $str."\n";
```

Результат:

```
Здравствуйте Анатолий мы знаем что ваша фамилия Рожков, поэтому Рожков Анатолий мы дарим вам подарок.
```